# Creating a "filtered" UI field

Tags: python, interface

I'm trying to figure out how to create a filtered field like the ones found in the modifier and constraints panels that only allow you to select from a list of Armatures in the scene. Couldn't find where this type of property is defined for the existing UI panels.

Comment: Afaik its implemented in rna_object.c with object_poll family of functions. Also of interest are rna_modifiers.c and rna_constraints.c and the object_set functions.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having the same issue, it's as simple as using `prop_search()` instead of `prop()` in the draw code.

Example:

```
row.prop_search(bpy.context.scene, "your_string_prop", bpy.data, "armatures")
```

to create a filtered field for the armatures in your current scene.

Comment: Note that you're only able to store the datablock's name in a `StringProperty()`. The custom property won't change along with the Armature name! Properties that reference datablocks via pointers can't be created with Python.