# Group input in panel with python

Tags: python, interface

How can I add an UI widget for a group input?

Example: *Physics > Smoke > Smoke Groups*

[image: Smoke Groups]

How can I create such a field in a panel with a python script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object selection box in addon](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7973/object-selection-box-in-addon) and [Create a filtered UI field](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16093/creating-a-filtered-ui-field)